# .NET Core 2.2 can't be published to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment, .net-core, publish

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 project and it can be run locally successfully. But when I try to publish it to Azure I get an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute.
Parameter name: root
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Tms.Core.Infrastructure.TmsFileProvider..ctor(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) in C:\Users\rover\Source\Repos\TMS\Libraries\Tms.Core\Infrastructure\TmsFileProvider.cs:line 23
   at Tms.WebApi.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\rover\Source\Repos\TMS\Web\Tms.WebApi\Startup.cs:line 222
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Tms.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\rover\Source\Repos\TMS\Web\Tms.WebApi\Program.cs:line 17
```

where Program class has the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Startup `ConfigureServices` method:

```
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var hostingEnvironment = provider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        CommonHelper.DefaultFileProvider = new TmsFileProvider(hostingEnvironment);
```

where:

```
    public TmsFileProvider(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) 
        : base(File.Exists(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath) ? Path.GetDirectoryName(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath) : hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath)
    {
        var path = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath ?? string.Empty;
        if (File.Exists(path))
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        BaseDirectory = path;
    }
```

(don't ask me about this code, it's not my code, I just have to use it)

I confused, why Azure knows my local path `C:\Users\rover\Source\Repos\TMS\Web\Tms.WebApi\`, where it's described and how to solve problem with deploy?

Comment: Is there any mini demo to reproduce your issue? How did you publish it to Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, `hostingEnvironment` can be null, when `wwwroot` folder does not exist. Then .NET Core throws such exception on Azure

Comment: Hey there, I encountered an issue which I think is similar to yours, after uploading my work form my work computer to azure, things still work fine in my work computer. But when I pulled it down to my home PC, the thing refused to run with the exception System.ArgumentException: 'The path must be absolute.' I do remember excluding my wwwroot folder from the git repo, is that the likely cause of my exception?